# Unable to execute my script in the right way using thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, lxml, python-multithreading

I've tried to create a scraper using python in combination with ***`Thread`*** to make the execution time faster. The scraper is supposed to parse all the shop names along with their phone numbers traversing multiple pages.

The script is running without any issues.  As I'm very new to work with ***`Thread`***, I can hardly understand I'm doing it in the right way.

This is what I've tried so far with:

```
import requests 
from lxml import html
import threading
from urllib.parse import urljoin 

link = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=coffee&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page={}"

def get_information(url):
    for pagelink in [url.format(page) for page in range(20)]:
        response = requests.get(pagelink).text
        tree = html.fromstring(response)
        for title in tree.cssselect("div.info"):
            name = title.cssselect("a.business-name span[itemprop=name]")[0].text
            try:
                phone = title.cssselect("div[itemprop=telephone]")[0].text
            except Exception: phone = ""
            print(f'{name} {phone}')

thread = threading.Thread(target=get_information, args=(link,))

thread.start()
thread.join()
```

> The problem being ***I can't find any difference in time or performance*** whether I run the above script using ***`Thread`*** or without using ***`Thread`***. If I'm going wrong, how can I execute the above script using ***`Thread`***?

***EDIT: I've tried to change the logic to use multiple links. Is it possible now? Thanks in advance.***

Comment: Threading will rarely make the code faster due to the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)

Comment: This is a single process starting one thread. There's no concurrency to the work being performed, so the execution time will be about the same.

Comment: Wrapping single process into Thread can make your script only slower... You should run several processes in parallel to decrease the execution time

Comment: If you need to scrape several links, you can try to scrape them simultaneously (almost simultaneously as mentioned GIL will not allow to actually run processes simultaneously) as `thread1 = threading.Thread(target=get_information, args=(link1,)); thread2 = threading.Thread(target=get_information, args=(link2,)); etc`

Comment: Please check out the edit to see if there is any option now to increase the performance. Thanks to everyone for your invaluable comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Threading to scrape several pages in paralel as below:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import threading
from urllib.parse import urljoin

link = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=coffee&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page={}"

def get_information(url):
    response = requests.get(url).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    for title in tree.cssselect("div.info"):
        name = title.cssselect("a.business-name span[itemprop=name]")[0].text
        try:
            phone = title.cssselect("div[itemprop=telephone]")[0].text
        except Exception: phone = ""
        print(f'{name} {phone}')

threads = []
for url in [link.format(page) for page in range(20)]:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=get_information, args=(url,))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Note that sequence of data will not be preserved. It means that if to scrape pages one by one sequence of extracted data will be:

```
page_1_name_1
page_1_name_2
page_1_name_3
page_2_name_1
page_2_name_2
page_2_name_3
page_3_name_1
page_3_name_2
page_3_name_3
```

while with Threading data will be mixed:

```
page_1_name_1
page_2_name_1
page_1_name_2
page_2_name_2
page_3_name_1
page_2_name_3
page_1_name_3
page_3_name_2
page_3_name_3
```

Comment: Sorry for my belated response, sir. It works just perfect.

Comment: I've been waiting for your online availability @sir Andersson. Please, take a look here at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245035/unable-to-use-two-threads-to-execute-two-functions-within-a-script) if you are not busy. Thanks.