# Unable to use two Threads to execute two functions within a script

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-multithreading

I've created a scraper using python in combination with `Thread` to make the execution faster. The scraper is supposed to parse all the links available within the webpage ended with different alphabets. It does parse them all.

However, I wish to parse all the `names` and `phone` numbers from those individual links using `Thread` again. The first portion I could manage to run using `Thread` but I can't get any idea how to create another `Thread` to execute the latter portion of the script?

I could have wrapped them within a single `Thread` but my intention is to know how to use two `Threads` to execute two functions.

***For the first portion: I tried like below and it worked***

```
import requests
import threading
from lxml import html

main_url = "https://www.houzz.com/proListings/letter/{}"

def alphabetical_links(mainurl):
    response = requests.get(link).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    return [container.attrib['href'] for container in tree.cssselect(".proSitemapLink a")]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    linklist = []
    for link in [main_url.format(chr(page)) for page in range(97,123)]:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=alphabetical_links, args=(link,))
        thread.start()
        linklist+=[thread]

    for thread in linklist:
        thread.join()
```

***My question is: How can I use `sub_links()` function within another `Thread`***

```
import requests
import threading
from lxml import html

main_url = "https://www.houzz.com/proListings/letter/{}"

def alphabetical_links(mainurl):
    response = requests.get(link).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    return [container.attrib['href'] for container in tree.cssselect(".proSitemapLink a")]

def sub_links(process_links):
    response = requests.get(process_links).text
    root = html.fromstring(response)

    for container in root.cssselect(".proListing"):
        try:
            name = container.cssselect("h2 a")[0].text
        except Exception: name = ""
        try:
            phone = container.cssselect(".proListingPhone")[0].text
        except Exception: phone = ""
        print(name, phone)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    linklist = []
    for link in [main_url.format(chr(page)) for page in range(97,123)]:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=alphabetical_links, args=(link,))
        thread.start()
        linklist+=[thread]

    for thread in linklist:
        thread.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update `alphabetical_links` with its own Threads:

```
import requests
import threading
from lxml import html

main_url = "https://www.houzz.com/proListings/letter/{}"


def alphabetical_links(mainurl):
    response = requests.get(mainurl).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    links_on_page = [container.attrib['href'] for container in tree.cssselect(".proSitemapLink a")]
    threads = []
    for link in links_on_page:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=sub_links, args=(link,))
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()


def sub_links(process_links):
    response = requests.get(process_links).text
    root = html.fromstring(response)

    for container in root.cssselect(".proListing"):
        try:
            name = container.cssselect("h2 a")[0].text
        except Exception: name = ""
        try:
            phone = container.cssselect(".proListingPhone")[0].text
        except Exception: phone = ""
        print(name, phone)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    linklist = []
    for link in [main_url.format(chr(page)) for page in range(97,123)]:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=alphabetical_links, args=(link,))
        thread.start()
        linklist+=[thread]


    for thread in linklist:
        thread.join()
```

Note that this is just an example of how to manage "inner Threads". Because of numerous threads that are starting at the same time your system might fail to start some of them due to lack of resources and you will get `RuntimeError: can't start new thread` exception. In this case you should try to implement *[ThreadPool](https://www.metachris.com/2016/04/python-threadpool/)*

Comment: Thanks for the script sir. I needed to know the logic and you showed me that very well. By the way, should I use a little delay within the script?

Comment: I don't think that delays will be much efficient in this case... ThreadingPool will allow you to limit concurrent threads number - more suitable for this case IMHO

Answer (score 0):

You can start more threads the same way you started the first one

```
from threading import Thread

t1 = Thread(target=alphabetical_links, kwargs={
    'mainurl':     link,
})
t1.start()

t2 = Thread(target=sub_links, kwargs={
    'process_links':     link,
})
t2.start()
```

Comment: Yep , I know this is how multiple threads can be executed but I can't use the logic within my above script. ***Can you show me how If you consider the above script as an example***? Thanks.